PDO Exception Unknown column when removing column from data table
I am currently working on removing deprecated columns from my database. After dropping a specific column, I encountered the following error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
'table.my_column' in 'field list'' in
/var/www/wap/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Statement/MysqlStatement.php:37

The error is triggered at this line of code:
$info = $this->Infos->find("InfoContact",["gid" => $info_id])->first();

It is using Cake\ORM\Query and the InfoContact entity does not contain any reference to the removed column.
I tried searching the entire code (using Ctrl+Shift+F) for the removed column name but found no explicit references to it. Given this, I think the issue might be related to schema caching in CakePHP. However, I am not entirely certain if caching is indeed the root cause—this is merely a hypothesis at this point.
There is schema caching configured to this project, but I have tried changing 'cacheMetadata' to false and adding versioning to the cake_model prefix but the error persists.
Also I have the cakephp/migrations in composer.json but it has no files that extends AbstractMigration
This is how caching is configured in the app.php file:
'Cache' => [         
    'default' => [
         'className' => FileEngine::class,
         'path' => CACHE,
         'url' => env('CACHE_DEFAULT_URL', null),
     ],
     /**
     * Configure the cache used for general framework caching.
     * Translation cache files are stored with this configuration.
     * Duration will be set to '+2 minutes' in bootstrap.php when debug = true
     * If you set 'className' => 'Null' core cache will be disabled.
     */
     '_cake_core_' => [
         'className' => FileEngine::class,
         'prefix' => 'myapp_cake_core_',
         'path' => CACHE . 'persistent/',
         'serialize' => true,
         'duration' => '+1 years',
         'url' => env('CACHE_CAKECORE_URL', null),
     ],
     /**
     * Configure the cache for model and datasource caches. This cache
     * configuration is used to store schema descriptions, and table listings
     * in connections.
     * Duration will be set to '+2 minutes' in bootstrap.php when debug = true
     */
     '_cake_model_' => [
         'className' => FileEngine::class,
         'prefix' => 'myapp_cake_model_',
         'path' => CACHE . 'models/',
         'serialize' => true,
         'duration' => '+1 years',
         'url' => env('CACHE_CAKEMODEL_URL', null),
     ],
     /**
     * Configure the cache for routes. The cached routes collection is built the
     * first time the routes are processed through config/routes.php.
     * Duration will be set to '+2 seconds' in bootstrap.php when debug = true
     */
     '_cake_routes_' => [
         'className' => FileEngine::class,
         'prefix' => 'myapp_cake_routes_',
         'path' => CACHE,
         'serialize' => true,
         'duration' => '+1 years',
         'url' => env('CACHE_CAKEROUTES_URL', null),
     ],
     'shortterm' => [
         'className' => FileEngine::class,
         'prefix' => 'myapp_short_',
         'path' => CACHE . 'views' . DS,
         'serialize' => true,
         'duration' => '+5 minutes'
     ]
     'Datasources' => [
         'default' => [
             'className' => Connection::class,
             'driver' => Mysql::class,
             'persistent' => false,
             'timezone' => env('APP_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE', 'UTC'),
             'flags' => [],
             'cacheMetadata' => true,
             'log' => false,
             'quoteIdentifiers' => true,
             'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
         ],
     ]


Schema caching does seem the most obvious cause. Just clear the cache?

I tried disabling the cache both by changing 'cacheMetadata' to false and by adding versioning to the cake_model prefix I don't know why it didn't work, but I just tried cleaning  it manually on the poc cli in the dev environment and it was successful.
But the problem now is that every time there's a deletion on the database I have to redeploy but then it takes a few minutes of errors witch is unideal in a prod env. Any ideas on what could be done?

Just add a cache clear to your deploy process.

The command is bin/cake cache clear_all etc. This should always be done with any (db) migration. Then there should be no issues if your code doesnt call invalid columns itself.
